# cordova app requestFileSystem fails after restarting the app after downloading much data

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, html5-filesystem

i am using cordova and its filesystem plugins to download a one page app from a server. After downloading all files the app redirects to the downloaded index.html in persistent storage. To be precise I am storing one html file and lots of images and pdfs and mp4 files in

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APPID]/Library/files/.

It all works fine and after downloading all files and the redirect to the index.html the one page app works fine too.

Every time the app is restarted it is sending a request to the server and ask for updates. If there are updates, they will be downloaded and again the redirect to the downloaded index.html.

Now a strange behavior occurs, after downloading much files. I am currently downloading 700 files and about 500MB. When the app starts the first time everything works as expected. All is downloaded and the one page app works and all the content is displayed.
After closing the app and restarting it, the window.requestFileSystem call fails with error QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR. 
There is enough space on device. I request 1GB and 500MB are downloaded and there are 8 GB free space on the device.
This error occurs only:

1. when app is relaunched
2. much data was downloaded on first app start. If I download only 20
   Files the error does not occur.

I know there is no size limit for apps on ios, so I am wondering what is this about.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading cordova-plugin-file to version 2.1.0 and cordova-plugin-file-transfer to version 1.2.1. Seems to be a bug in older versions.